# Setting up gitignore on Windows 10 with git bash

Tags: git

i'm running windows 10 with git bash and am trying to setup a .gitignore file. The file exist in my repos root directory. For some reason git seems to ignore the content of this file. I've tried creating a project called test1 and i want to ignore certain files.

Below is my .gitignore

```
/test1/Debug/
/test1/proj1.*
/test1/.vs/
```

As I understand it. This should ignore everything in the Debug folder. Everything in test1 folder that starts with proj1 will be ignored. Finally everything in the .vs folder will be ignored aswell. Sadly this does not work,

I've been instructed to use  `git rm -r --cached` to clear files that might previously been tracked. This does nothing but print the usage message. I've also tried to save the .gitignore file with ANSI encoding this makes no difference either. :<

Comment: Is `test1` a subfolder of your repo?

Comment: Yes I missed to include /test1/Debug/ in my post. i edited the main post now

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i've just reinstalled Windows after using Linux for a long time so I had forgotten how much file extensions matter. What existed on my github.com page was the file .gitignore.txt which didn't work at all. So in the Windows 10 file explorer i clicked "view" and then checked the box for "file name extension" and I was able to remove the ".txt" extension

On the next git push everything worked as expected.